# uploading image/audio/video to server in iphone..?

Tags: iphone, uploading

How can we upload audio/video/images to any  server in iphone...

Comment: You need to accept the previous answers first,otherwise you will not get good help.

Comment: First accept the previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

Read [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html).